# Get order by cart id used

Tags: cart

is there a way that I can get an order by selecting the cart id that was used to produce the order in the database?

I use the following code to get the cart id

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$cartId = 99;
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('quote_id', $cartId);
$order = $orders->getFirstItem();
if ($order->getId()) {
    //it means the order exists
    //do something with $order
}
else {
    //there is no order for $cartId
}
```

Comment: is the way I get my cart id right?

Comment: I tried this code and it shows a number but its a 4 digit number and doesn't appear in the orders in my backend.

Comment: @Mahan. What shows "a 4 digit number"?

Answer (score 2):

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($quoteId, 'quote_id');
```

Comment: this doesn't show anything... :(

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't show anything"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
$cartId = 64;
$_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($cartId, 'quote_id');
```